Request to reopen question which got closed and deleted by a moderator
This question has an explanation of the problem and a pattern that is tried by the OP.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952798/need-help-to-construct-regex
To me this question is not unclear at all, it is explained with the wrong result and has an expected result.
A moderator single handedly closed and removed the question, which I think is a wrong approach.
Can this question be reopened?

Voted to reopen, this looks on topic, although OP could clarify exactly what their input specification is a bit clearer--it's hard to infer from the 2 examples given which are quite different. Aside: it's amazing to me that people still attempt to answer regex questions. Don't 98% of them get closed as a dupe of the one canonical? (statistic made up)

It does seem weird that it was deleted, but i don't see any value that was lost.

The Title ("Need help to construct regex") is completely useless (= non-descriptive), for sure...!

Re-opened already

"Need help to construct regex" can describe basically any regex question on the site.

Nothing of value was lost. The question is just noise. One specific user was helped with their current homework/task, fine. But frankly, I fail to see what's the point of actually wanting this around, besides the possible reputation gain. If one is willing to spend time answering something of so little value, some effort should at least be spent polishing the specimen into something more respectable, IMO.

@Yivi From specific answers often comes canonicals. It's hard to predict. Probably not here, sure, but not every question needs to be canonical anyway--not OP's fault that their task happens to be fairly specific. We can still answer it and add value. All that matters is that it's answerable--canonicals happen naturally, and some questions become more generally useful than others.

My point here is that a single moderator thought lets immediately remove this clearly explained question, where SO is meant for.

SO is meant to be a repository of useful questions and answers. There's nothing useful about the thousandth "debug my regex" question. The least it could do is have a descriptive title.

You keep insisting on "a single moderator", which is not really relevant. Moderator actions are supposed to be binding, and their votes to be executed without having to consult a committee. That's how's supposed to work. Yes, these actions can also be wrong and can be contested; but there is nothing inherently wrong with a moderator doing something like this single-handedly.

I'm generally against the manual deletion of questions like this because it's wasted effort. Now there's a dozen plus people involved in a question that was just sitting idle in a database simply acting as one more low quality source to feed LLM's. It'd never come up in search given the title and lack of a clear definable question and over 5 years it gained a measly 70ish views. but i'm certainly against it being reopened... now we have a chance to make it roomba worthy so it never comes back, or to fix it so it's a useful addition. Which one makes more sense?

Moderators singlehandedly close and delete questions all the time.  If a user wants to contest that decision, they are welcome to ask on meta as you did. This way the community gets to have a voice and they can also cast their own close/reopen votes or up/down votes.

@Dharman No? Because our delvotes are binding, closing and deleting questions is reserved for exceptional cases precisely because it can't be undone by users without moderator intervention if it's fixed. You should not be closing and deleting questions as a mod on a regular basis -- leave deletion for roomba and/or 10k users instead

@Zoe I disagree. Where does it say that? Mods are encouraged to use their powers. That's why we have them.

I agree w/ Dharman--while moderators should be aware of the binding nature of their delete votes, that should not dissuade them from using the power regularly where they legitimately feel it is warranted.

All that effort to get the deletion of that question reversed only for it to be deleted.  Why exactly did we waste our time to restore the question only to close it as a duplicate then delete it? There are not enough close reasons to cover every possibility, so questions will be closed with the "wrong" close reason, does not mean they shouldn't be closed and deleted.

It's regex. It's one of the not-programming-but-still-allowed tags which have zero chance of being managed correctly on Stack Overflow. This happens and will continue to happen. Especially if you link to it on meta and you put it under the eyes of people who treat the site rules like doctrine.

I am also a little irked by the reference to "powers" here, that betrays the wrong mindset. You have privileges. Privileges come with a code of conduct.

A question needs to be useful to the community. That is its main goal. A question cannot just be a statement about the author trying to do something or needing help with something. People search for solutions to concrete problem statements. This question has a horrible title and there isn't even a question asked in this question. It's just a description of what the author was doing.
I would be ok with it being undeleted and reopened if it was edited to be a proper and useful question. Right now it has no value to the community and I see no way that we could make it into a unique and useful question.

Thanks for needlessly closing and deleting a question that is clear. If the title is a reason to remove it, you can remove a lot of questions (or just update the title and let it be)

I'd generally prefer people who are invested in the question, such as the answerer or even the OP, to perform an edit to an entirely useless title rather than any random passer's-by. this Q&A pair has existed for 5 years, it's had plenty of time to be fixed.

@Thefourthbird And that's exactly what I am doing. I am cleaning up useless questions. And the question is not clear. We may disagree, but as I have just explained, I can't even see a question in that post.

If the answerer or the OP can turn this post into a proper question then it would be great. Maybe it would become findable and helpful to others. But in the past 5 years nobody did that. I try to salvage questions that look reasonable but only have a bad title or some small quality issues, but when I see a question that I can't improve myself I will just close and delete it.

Nobody commented to ask OP to clarify in that 5 year span, and they accepted the answer, so it's not reasonable to expect them to improve their question absent of nothing. The question was satisfactorily clear enough to be answered and accepted, so it was resolved to the satisfaction of the community, as far as OP had been appraised of. There's a pre-deletion feedback process that should happen.

@Thefourthbird I think a reasonable takeaway here is that when answering, you should try to improve a question so that it can be useful to a future person with a similar problem (the Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator badge series exists to encourage this). An answerer is ideally situated to write a better title, as they understand the root issue. As-is, even assuming the question is clear (which is not beyond debate), it's not in a position to help anyone else.

I deleted the question again.
It was a mercy kill for several reasons.
First, OP was not the one who brought the question to the Meta and no matter how poor it was, it still doesn't deserve the pile of downvotes it was getting.
Next, there was very little value there to begin with, and it was not being improved to the point we can honestly say it will have bright future as a good duplicate sign post.
I would also urge the Meta folks, to have more consideration when voting both up and down in such situations as they are not making the discussion and resolution of such issues easier.

At this point, probably a good call. The consensus of this thread seems to reduce to "don't ask regex questions on Stack Overflow" as far as I can tell, since this is well above average for a regex question (clear input, expected result, attempt, answerable and answered), and fourth bird is pretty much one of the top regex SMEs we have.

@ggorlen It's really not clear...for example, the answer assumes, for no clear reason, that the operation can have at most one underscore. It's even possible that the format is not actually unambiguous: there is not a completely clear indication which  fields can have underscores; if the version can have underscores, it's ambiguous. It's probably reasonable to assume that the example data has underscores in every field where that's possible; however, that still doesn't fix the ambiguity regarding the operation field (were I answering, I would have assumed an unlimited number of underscores).

@RyanM Sure, it's not perfectly clear, just above average (check out all the "similar questions" linked from it if you want to see some truly awful questions that weren't deleted--check out this one or this one, to pick a random couple examples. Pure "gimmeh teh codez"). But the backlash against it is way out of proportion. It's a "leave a comment asking for clarification"-level issue.

@RyanM And yes, I'm aware of the meta effect. Just agreeing with "it still doesn't deserve the pile of downvotes it was getting." and "I would also urge the Meta folks, to have more consideration when voting both up and down in such situations as they are not making the discussion and resolution of such issues easier."

@ggorlen That first one is completely clear, it just had a bad title (which has now been improved to a title that describes a problem someone else might have).  The second one is in fact pretty bad; I closed it, and the system will automatically delete it in the near future.

@RyanM The requirements are clear but there's no attempt, so it's off topic. There's no technical question, just a work order. Some in this thread have mentioned relevance based on views--this has 87 views since 2012 and I'm sure a chunk of those are from today. I'm not sure I agree on relevance based on that metric alone, though. Anyway, it's a bit of an aside from the main point--there are thousands of worse regex questions than the one here. (I've answered over 100 regex questions so I think I have a pretty good idea). Doesn't excuse the issues here, but it's definitely above-average.

@ggorlen when 99% of the questions people try to ask about regex are "here's the entire regex; why does it (match the wrong things) | (not match the wrong things)?", then yes, the correct response is going to create an impression of "don't ask regex questions on Stack Overflow". The fact that regex is a one-liner code golf language (that people fail to recognize as a language at all) does not excuse a failure to produce a proper MRE, nor to apply standard debugging skills (including basic logical reasoning) before asking.

@ggorlen "The requirements are clear but there's no attempt, so it's off topic." Lack of problem-solving effort is not a close reason.

@RyanM That's not what I've understood. Anyone can just dump problems without asking a specific technical question about their code attempt? We only answer specific, technical programming questions, not fulfill work orders. Those are for freelancing sites. If nothing has been attempted, then there's no technical problem yet, just a business one, so it's "too broad" for SO. #3 in your link doesn't apply, because they haven't actually encountered a technical problem yet. Those only arise after making an attempt.

@RyanM Here's another example: "Please write a React component that has an input box and a list of items that the user has entered. When the user presses Enter after typing into the input, the text from the input is appended to the list and the input box is cleared." This is a business request, too broad and off-topic, even though the requirements are crystal clear. The regex question we're discussing is identical, except a different technology. It's not a matter of effort, per se, it's a matter of whether they're asking a technical question or placing a work order for a freelancer or ChatGPT.

@ggorlen "Anyone can just dump problems without asking a specific technical question?" Of course not, but that has nothing to do with an attempt. The question is whether a specific technical question is being asked, & a description of a specific, reasonably focused task is a specific technical question (the question, if not specifically stated, is implied to be "How do I accomplish this task?"). Debugging questions are worse than how-tos.  "We only answer specific, technical programming questions, not work orders." Sure, but again: nothing to do with an attempt. ... [1/2]

[2/2] A work order is a list of requirements; emphasis on list (your React example is a good example of this). A single requirement, such as "validate that a string contains only digits and hyphens" (in some sense, this is 2 requirements, but it's a common enough use case—US social security numbers, for example—that it's effectively one requirement), is exactly the sort of question that we want. "If nothing has been attempted, then there's no technical problem yet, just a motivational one." This does not follow. If one has no idea how to do something, what useful attempt can be made?

@RyanM You begin by writing a regex to match any string, and refine it to meet some requirements. A question needs to show some level of baseline knowledge. If you don't know how to even write a regex that matches anything, then you don't have the technical background to be asking. At least sketch out a solution attempt and try to build any small piece of the puzzle. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/: 'Can you write “Hello world” in this language?'. "Write this function for me" or "write this regex for me" or "write this app for me" are all too broad.

@RyanM If one has zero technical background and can't even open a regex editor and begin writing .* or \d+, then they should at the very least state that context when asking a question. Anyway, hopefully ChatGPT has taken over most of these trivial, uninteresting questions that really can be answered by an FAQ/wiki-style post, web search/article or making small modifications to an existing answer(s) on SO.

@RyanM Also, our question drafter prompt says "What did you try and what were you expecting? Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted. Minimum 20 characters." Why would it bother with this if it's not a requirement? Most askers fill this in with something BS like "I tried some stuff but it didn't work. I'm expecting it to work but it didn't work." which isn't specific enough to be useful. So we really do need some kind of attempt.

@RyanM (sorry for all the comments), looping back to the main regex question at hand in this thread, at least OP there has clearly very much attempted something and is asking a technical question about their failing attempt. Unfortunately, they chose a bad title, have somewhat unclear requirements (albeit were clear enough for one of our regex SMEs to answer), and have the misfortune of having a fairly specific regex problem (which nobody has shown me guidelines indicating is prohibited, but is clearly a major issue for much of the meta crowd in this thread).

@ggorlen *"our question drafter prompt says [to describe what you tried.] Why would it bother with this if it's not a requirement?" It is advice, not required...and whether it is a net positive has been called into question because (as you note) most of the attempts are not useful, & questions are frequently better off without them. If it's clear without an attempt, adding one is just noise that often results in answers that are less useful to others. For example, how would an attempt improve the 2nd-highest-score question on SO?

@RyanM Sure, there are exceptions. I agree that git questions don't qualify for attempts generally (it's a command line programming tool, not code). Anyway, my point in all of this is that I don't think the OP regex question is as bad as it's been slammed here, just a typical regex question. Whether or not the one I raised is on topic or not is a bit of a sideline. To me it's pretty obviously "gimmeh teh regex" but that's another debate I suppose. The point stands that there are zillions of worse regex questions than the primary OP one being discussed. Regex is touchy, which is why I avoid it.

@ggorlen I do agree that most regex Qs are pretty bad and of little future value, and that this is far from the worst. Ideally, this would have been edited to, say, "How do I split a string into fields if the delimiter may also appear in the field itself?", which is a problem someone else might have. Alas, that wasn't done at the time, and it's a bit harder to do later. But what I want to stress is that the problem with most regex Qs isn't lack of effort/attempt; it's a list of multiple idiosyncratic requirements that no one else will ever have. It's a focus problem, not an effort one.

@RyanM I still don't think it's a problem if requirements happen to be idiosyncratic. That's not OP's fault. Nobody has given me a reference in the help docs that says "if your requirements are idiosyncratic, don't ask on SO". It's presumptuous in general to assume nobody else will have the same problem, unlikely as it may be. For all we know, this specific log format is some proprietary thing that needs to be parsed to work with some legacy system, and others will want to find out how. Happens all the time where I find answers to my problems in low-view, old, obscure, unloved threads.

@RyanM But the regex tag in particular is cursed and this question does have flaws (title, ambiguity), and probably won't be useful to anyone in fact, so I probably picked the wrong hill to fight on here. I see other questions that are a lot better (or even perfectly well-asked) that get smashed down by the "this is too specific to one person's problem" rationale that I'll be looking to fight for. I do think there's a middle ground of high-quality, low-view questions that are being unnecessarily closed, between "everything should be useful to multiple users" and "anything goes" crowds.

@ggorlen I think that what we learned here is that if one answers unclear questions and is not fine with that answer being removed some time in the future, one should always edit the question and improve it as much as possible.

@DalijaPrasnikar I'm totally on board with that, no doubt. Probably would have avoided the whole issue if the answerer had asked for clarification, context and made the title clearer. I guess they assumed since their answer was accepted that it wasn't necessary, but I'd still have been more critical and tried to get the requirements edited to be totally clear. Many askers generally don't edit or improve the question once the working answer arrives, unfortunately. But if, after clarification, it was still a pretty obscure pattern, that seems perfectly fine to me.

The "question drafter" (i.e. Ask Question Wizard (2022)) is fundamentally and severely flawed, to the extent that nothing it does or says should be taken as normative or even really indicative of policy.

Let's consider the crux of the question. OP had this regex:
(?<programName>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(?<other>.+)_(?<boardSN>I.+)_(?<entityNameProgramVersion>.+)_(?<operation>.+)_

and sought to match it at the beginning of this input:
CLOB_ABCD_6KW_SYSTEM_609-784_IWHT91831863_197_ACB_01_2019-05-02T07.03.27

And expected to capture:

CLOB as the programName
ABCD_6KW_SYSTEM_609-784 as the other
IWHT91831863 as the boardSN
197 as the entityNameProgramVersion
ACB_01 as the operation

... but instead, the 197 part ended up in the boardSN, and ACB_01 was split up to form the entityNameProgramVersion and operation.
The somewhat irritating thing about discussing specific questions on Meta is that sometimes I have to actually answer the question to provide enough context for the policy discussion ;)
This happens, of course, because the regex uses only standard greedy matches. The basic idea of OP's regex is to split the string at _ separators, but only consider certain of those separators - because most of the values are also allowed to contain that character. OP's idea is to disallow _ in the programName and require the boardSN to start with I - so those results are kosher, as long as the other doesn't need to contain _I. But then we get to parsing the part starting with the boardSN.
The trailing _ on the regex matches the last _ in the input, but having backtracked that far, we are left with four _-separated items (IWHT91831863, 197, ACB and 01) to distribute among the last three capturing groups. Since the matches are greedy, the first of these capturing groups (the boardSN) will get the first two of those.

So. What's wrong with the question?

The question is unclear because a) the question is framed like "what's wrong with this code?", but the code is a single line buried under paragraphs of problem specification. (If it were intended as a how-to question, then it would be clearly unsuitable, since we don't write custom code to specification.)

The question is again unclear because the names of the capturing groups don't match the names used in describing the desired and actual results. Yes, this is nitpicking, but seeing those two sets of names is disorienting - especially since both sets look like identifier names in a program rather than a plain language description.

The question is again unclear because of the overall poor copyediting. The title gives us no indication of what to expect; there is no up-front description of the intended purpose of the code; there are some minor grammatical errors, etc. We're essentially dropped into the middle of the OP's thought process without any orientation and the problem is not introduced very well (what should "find a regex for the following lines" mean, especially when followed up by a single line?). In short, the question completely fails at checking off the boxes described in How to Ask.

The question lacks a proper MRE. I know that must sound absurd at first blush: obviously the problem is reproducible (and we don't really need to see framing code to apply the regex, because... that's obviously not where the problem is); and the inputs and the regex are a single line each. How could that not be minimal? Well, the thing is, we don't count length in lines or bytes; we count it in conceptual steps, and wish to remove everything unnecessary. In this case, since the first two capturing groups apparently do what they're supposed to, we shouldn't see them, but only see the interesting part of the regex - and we should see simplified examples that are suited to be matched with just that part of the regex.

The question is arguably a duplicate - and has been re-closed as such. Once one infers OP's thought process (which should have been explicitly stated), we conclude that OP expected (?<boardSN>I.+)_ to match only up to the immediate next underscore - a classic misunderstanding of regex that has been discussed countless times.


Now, most of these issues are easily fixable by editing - and in fact I intend to do so as soon as I post this answer. But there isn't any getting around the fact that this is yet another "regexes are greedy by default" problem. The accepted answer points this out and shows both viable workarounds (using character classes to force a shorter match, and using explicitly reluctant qualifiers). The suggested modification for the other group isn't actually necessary, which shows a pitfall of failing to minimize the example. The answer is also confused, in that it seems to imply that one approach is necessary in one case and the other approach in the other cases, when that simply isn't true.

At this point I'd like to emphasize: Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?
Closing the question as a duplicate helps the OP and saves the time of would-be answerers. By having such duplicates, effort can be focused on making its answers as high quality as possible. When everyone works on the same set of answers instead of repeating the same work, higher quality is possible. The OP, meanwhile, gets to benefit from that high quality immediately, without being distracted by a spontaneous attempt at answering the same question (which is also hindered by the extra difficulty in identifying that it's the same question). Of course, that only really helps when it happens right away; but closing questions that should be closed, helps keep the site clean.
Expecting OP to meet these high standards helps everyone. When standards are met, it becomes much easier to recognize duplicates as duplicates, which makes it easier to close them as duplicates, which makes it easier to help OP right away. When the question isn't a duplicate, having questions that meet standards makes them easier to answer clearly, and also makes it easier for other people with the same problem to find the question and recognize that it is, indeed, the same problem.
Now that it's closed again, this question should IMO be deleted (even though I'm going to make edits to improve it anyway, just to make a point). The problem is that there is no value in the question as a signpost to future Stack Overflow readers. The title "Need help to construct regex" can't ever be helpful to anyone using a search engine. True, people with essentially the same problem might not know what to look for. But even if they thought to try something that generic and non-descript (and if you're really at that point, why not just use an actual discussion forum?) they would have no hope of correctly identifying this question as the one with the answer they seek, out of a horde of countless other questions with similarly useless titles that are about completely different problems. (For reference: the site search currently shows me 260,388 questions in regex; and I'd hazard a guess that approximately 260,388 of them could be accurately described as OP trying to get help with creating a regex.) To fix this problem would require completely replacing the title. But there is no good (i.e. searchable) title to use here that isn't already covered by other duplicates for the canonical. (Keep in mind that, in addition to use in search engines, titles exist to serve curators who search for duplicates to close other questions.)

I propose three general curation philosophies as a simplification to help discuss the question at hand:

Questions should aim to be generalized and have value for a reasonably large audience of users on the site. The ideal question is a canonical/wiki/FAQ for maximum value, and questions that are too specific to a single asker's needs should be downvoted/closed/deleted. Helping an asker solve their specific problem is unimportant, except for the extent to which it helps the community.
Questions can be fairly single-user specific. As long as they're reasonably well-researched, reasonably novel, clear and answerable, they're on topic, even if the problem is unique to one user, or a few users.
Virtually everything is on topic. The SO community should accept just about any programming question. If a prospective answerer can't help or finds an issue with a question, leave it alone instead of taking curation action.

I'm squarely in camp #2 (I'm not going to spend time discussing camp #3--the debate in this thread is between camps #1 and #2, but it's worth pointing out because some camp #2 can be mistakenly lumped in with camp #3).
There's nothing in our guidelines that says a question needs to be, or attempt to be, popular or generalized to any extent for it to be on topic. If it happens to become a canonical naturally (mainly through SEO luck), that's great, and we should strive to steer things towards generality and helping future visitors when possible. But general solutions often come from specific problems, and we need a specific, reproducible problem to make an issue concrete and answerable.
If a topic is a duplicate, but the asker has made a reasonable attempt to find the duplicate, or there is a reasonable variation on the fundamental question, I don't see a problem with erring on the side of leaving a question up, assuming it's on topic in all other aspects. Perhaps a duplicate vote may be necessary, but not moderator deletion.
Camp #1 users tend to delete and dupe-hammer any question that bears passing resemblance to a canonical thread, or conceivably could have been found elsewhere, or if the question is too specific to one user's problem. The tag winds up devolving into a handful of canonical posts that bear little relevance to anyone's specific issue.
This phenomenon has been discussed extensively in threads like What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate? so I won't rehash the issues with this style of curation here, but overaggressive curation to this extent is harmful to the community.
Now, the question we're discussing in this thread seems to fall more or less in camp #2. It's almost certainly not going to become canonical (in general, it's hard to predict which ones will), but it's a practical, answerable programming problem with a reproducible attempt, which seems on topic to me. I've found solutions to deep, annoying issues in seldom-used technologies solved by threads that are 6 years old and have 30 views. If those had been deleted because they never become popular (impossible in small tags like, say, matter.js), I'd probably never have found an answer.
My main issue with the question is that, like many regex questions, the scope of valid inputs is unclear. OP presents
CLog_DMT_HPCC2_IWHT91731695_242_AFT1_2019-05-02T07.51.43

as the first input to match, but then presents
CLOB_ABCD_6KW_SYSTEM_609-784_IWHT91831863_197_ACB_01_2019-05-02T07.03.27

as a non-working variant. But what exactly is the specification here? Does the answer also need to match
CLOT_XY%X_!@#$_S%%$$$$_64$09-@@_IWHT91831863_197_ACB_01_2019-05-02T07.03.27

next? OP should clarify exactly what the set of valid inputs is to avoid an endless slope of "OK, thanks, but now match X input I didn't tell you about yet" follow-ups which I've seen many times back in my regex days. (Ironically, I left the tag because most of my answers were deleted before they had a chance to be useful to a wider audience beyond the asker.)
The title can also be improved. It's too generic, although it's hard to come up with a better one based on the question content. Maybe if OP provided more context, like "Regex pattern to match nginx logs" (I'm making that up, it's not an nginx log, but you get the idea), the additional context might make it a commonly-searched question, or help answerers determine that it's really an XY problem and there may be a more direct solution than a regex.
I can see the question being closed as "unclear what you're asking", and follow-up comments being posted to address these medium-level concerns, but a moderator deletion on the grounds of "not useful to the community" seems like overreach.
Since the deletion, the question has been reopened, then closed as a dupe. This is a better outcome than deletion, but it's closed as a dupe of an overly-broad, FAQ/Wiki-style canonical that OP or future visitors to the thread aren't likely to have the context to be able to adapt to their particular scenario, or even be expected to find in advance. They'd have to know what their problem is to be able to search for something like "Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Qualifiers".

"There's nothing in our guidelines that says a question needs to attempt to be, or be a candidate for being canonical for it to be on topic." that's a strawman. I don't think there are a lot of people who believe every single question should be a canonical. But questions are expected to help more than one person.

@VLAZ It's not a strawman. The other answer states: "A question needs to be useful to the community. That is its main goal. A question cannot just be a statement about the author trying to do something or needing help with something." What made them arrive at these conclusions? These are pulled out of thin air, from the minds of camp #1, not our site guidelines. Please show me the guideline that says "if your question is too unique and not useful to a certain number of future visitors, don't ask".

The whole of 1. is a strawman you've concocted. Then you defeated it with the claim that it's not in the guidelines. It's not. It's also not a view hold by many or maybe even any.

It's not a strawman. There are a small number users in camp #1, that clearly feel this way, but they have disproportionate power. See the regex link for the most visible example. Why else would people delete and blast away questions just because they're too specific to one user? I had a question I'd answered blasted away this morning for that very reason, even though nobody could come up with a decent duplicate.

"It's not a strawman." it is.

How is it a strawman? How do you suggest I change it so you feel it isn't? It seems like a clear recap of the viewpoint given in this answer and the behavior of certain power users on the site: in short, the view is that all questions need to be canonical, and if they're not, blast 'em away, either by deletion or dupe, plus DVs, as was clearly done to the post in this thread (and countless others policed by certain camp #1 power users most users who've been on the site for awhile are familiar with, if they've strayed into one of their tags).

In fact, one of the users who voted to close this regex question against a random general FAQ-style wiki thread also dupe hammered the question I answered today. So yeah, it's clearly the same handful of people behaving exactly as I've described in camp #1, killing most questions in their favorite tags and being generally detrimental to the body of knowledge. The problem really does exist in regex as well as other tags and is well-documented. Not something I made up.

You've taken the most extreme cases of several disparate views, lumped them together, said users either belong there, or in the other extreme of "SO is toxic any time "the mods" (really the community) close or downvote anything." or a somewhat reasonable middle-ground. It's just a caricature of a hardened zealot you present for the sole purpose to discredit it and undermine anything that's not #2. Dharman's answer notably doesn't mention anything about documentation, so "If the question exists in the documentation, has been asked before, or is too specific to one user's situation," doesn't

apply.  Nor does "Helping OP solve their specific problem is irrelevant, unless it happens to be a rare potential canonical." appear in the answer. Only really part about it being useful to a large is there. Even then, it seems like Dharman randomly decided this question cannot be useful to others. It's hardly just a whim - we have specific metrics. The question got 70 views over a period of 5 years. That has not been useful.

It's an interesting POV. The site is community-run so there will always be different opinions on what the site should be and what type of questions are ok. However, it's inherent in the design of this site that questions should be useful to other people and not just the OP. Otherwise, the question would be deleted after being answered (like in help desk software) and not searchable from the search engines. If the question is answerable then we may never know if it will ever be helpful to at least 1 more person, but if we are trying to direct people to better answers then dup closures are ok.

And occasional deletion of a very low-quality question can help people not waste time when they are searching for their problem's answer on SO. There's no point in actively seeking out questions to delete, but a mod or SME can review it if they encounter it. And if others disagree then it's also ok. Questions can be undeleted and reopened.

@VLAZ Sure, I've presented a simplification of multiple viewpoints. That's just how categorization and analysis of trends works. Yes, I'm trying to discredit it, that's the point. It's not a caricature because all of the beliefs for camp #1 I've mentioned are backed up by the actions the people in the camp take on a daily basis. Again, we don't require that questions hit a certain number of views to be on topic or useful. You've invented that just now. Maybe one of those views was someone who saved their company $100k by fixing a serious bug. Who knows? Usefulness isn't 1:1 with views.

@Dharman I already discussed that in my post "it's worth pointing out because some camp #1-ers seem to think camp #2 is the same as camp #3". I'm not advocating for camp #3, where anything goes. I massively DV and VTC questions (check my stats), but I am totally fine with questions that are good, albeit appear very specific--the difference between camp #1 and #2. I'm advocating for allowing high-enough-quality questions on the site even if they're not destined to be canonical or won't necessarily help more than a few users (you never know who'll be helped).

Neither am I. I think I would put myself in camp #2 but I think many people fall somewhere in between.

@Dharman Sure, it's a simplification, but I think it's a useful one for the discussion here. But your answer and action taken here seems very camp #1 to me. "A question needs to be useful to the community. That is its main goal. A question cannot just be a statement about the author trying to do something or needing help with something." None of this is in the site guidelines for asking questions, it's a concoction invented by camp #1 used to justify blasting away questions and answers that aren't canonical enough for them. If it's in the guidelines, I'd be happy to see it and stand corrected.

Actually, this meta thread is a perfect example of some of my arguments. It's a specific question about a particular regex  deletion that has general relevance, just like a lot of specific technical questions on SO that have general relevance. OP solves their particular problem, and helps a lot of other future visitors in the process. But the process has to happen naturally--OP in the meta thread didn't set out to create a wiki/FAQ, nor should we be dupe hammering it (we're not, but the point is that the same pattern applies to the regular site as well). It's a good, answerable question.

A question doesn't need to be canonical to be useful to someone else. It might be that a question will never help anyone else either. But I do advocate for the deletion of questions that are unclear or poor duplicates which will only ever waste time of someone else. We don't need to keep every question around.

@Dharman Again, I already dealt with "We don't need to keep every question around" in my answer. That's camp #3 and I'm clearly against that. That's a strawman argument because it's not the one I'm making. I'm in favor of keeping sufficiently good questions around, regardless of how popular they are. There are thousands of questions that are much less clear than the one being discussed here that need to be cleaned up. Those questions are truly unanswerable, garbage questions that camp #3 wants to keep. Different category from those that are reasonable but don't happen to be popular (camp #2).

I don't think anyone abused their dupe hammer/vote here or on the other question mentioned. Duplicate closure is good, not only for the OP, but for the site as a whole. It's answering the question without reposting the same solution over and over again. These last comments are off-topic, so I will remove them. If you want to discuss the duplicate closure of the other question, please post a new meta question.

@Dharman Thanks for your input and feel free to clean up the thread. I think both your actions on the regex question here and Karl's on many Python posts over the years are out of line with the site guidelines. But I guess I'm outgunned. Still, nobody has shown me the guideline I requested--happy to change my view if I'm presented with evidence.

I didn't see your request for guidelines so I don't know what you wish to see. Maybe I missed it somewhere. I also don't think I follow what site guidelines you think we have overstepped.

@Dharman Where do the site guidelines say anything to the effect of "if your question is not popular enough, too specific to your own problem, or not destined to become canonical, it will be closed and deleted"?

BTW, This edit seems really invasive and conflicts with the author's intent, changing the input CLog_DMT_HPCC2_IWHT91731695_242_AFT1_2019-05-02T07.51.43 to I123_456_ABC_01_test. How is that allowed?

@ggorlen "if your question is not popular enough, too specific to your own problem, or not destined to become canonical, it will be closed and deleted" no one here but you had said that. Where are you getting that from? Don't try to extrapolate normal curation activities into whatever you assume users are doing.

@AbdulAzizBarkat "A question needs to be useful to the community. That is its main goal. A question cannot just be a statement about the author trying to do something or needing help with something". There's no evidence for that. It's not what I assume users are doing, it's what they are doing. See for example What's up with the [regex] tag? It seems many on-topic [regex] tag were removed? to get an idea of the trend in this tag, if you're not aware of it.

Nowhere does it say that. And I think you misunderstood something because neither I nor Karl claimed anything like that.

@Dharman That's what your actions say, I'm simply clarifying the concept of "camp #1" for the sake of argument. It's the "blast anything that isn't canonical" camp and it very much exists. Check the many meta discussions about overaggressive closures in the Regex tags (Python too, but I haven't found a meta post about the phenomenon yet--will look). If you can improve my characterization or point out how it differs from the actions of certain overaggressive power users, please do.

There's a whole lot of nuance beign completely left out between #1 and #2. I can care less about canonicalization, and certainly support questions primarily aimed at helping a single user, as your group 2 suggests. However, posts must have some use to future visitors if they are to remain undeleted on the site. regex questions statistically never do.

My actions??? Sorry if my actions gave you this impression. I don't advise deleting or closing questions simply because they are unpopular. We don't have a close reason for being too specific either (although it used to exist at the beginning of this site).

@KevinB Like I said in the post and repeated earlier in the comments, it's a simplification for sake of argument. It's a normal way to make a point. There's always loss of nuance when you create a model of something.

@Dharman You deleted a question simply because you decided it wasn't useful to the community, based on views and a bad title. How do you know for sure that that question hasn't helped someone get unblocked? Anyway, my answer isn't exactly about this one question, it's about larger trends I've seen and an aggressive curation philosophy that has no grounds in the guideliens.

The topic of this meta post was me closing and deleting a question which I believed to be unclear. The counterargument was that the OP was helped by the answerer so the question must have been clear enough. The question was reopened and then reclosed. I still argue that the way it was written before was unclear. After Karl's edit, it became significantly better, but it's still a duplicate. So the second half of the conundrum still exists: is this question useful enough to keep around as a signpost.

@Dharman Karl's edit totally changed the author's intent and is a non-starter, clearly against the guidelines. It also invalidated the accepted answer. The reclosure against a super-broad FAQ/wiki is another symptom, but it's the same problem (as deletion) of certain users being allergic to any question that's not framed as an FAQ/wiki/canonical.

I did not delete the question simply based on views and title. I deleted it because I believed it to be unclear and unsalvagable.

Sorry, but I can't see how Karl's edit changed the intent. I think the question still asks the same thing.

@Dharman My mistake--VLAZ made the "the question got 70 views over a period of 5 years. That has not been useful." argument, not you. Karl's edit changed the input and added presumptions about what parts of the regex worked and which didn't, which is critical to any regex question. The edit basically removed the failing input entirely CLOB_ABCD_6KW_SYSTEM_609-784_IWHT91831863_197_ACB_01_2019-05-02T07.03.27. The difference between that and the original input that OP claims works as expected is the crux of the question.

Put another way, i feel you're dumping a bunch of people into camp #1 who don't agree with most of what you've outlined in group #1 but also don't agree with your stance here as someone from group #2, for the purpose of "discrediting them".

@KevinB I appreciate the feedback--how can I improve these characterizations? I want to present a non-strawman version of #1, then show that this ultra-aggressive interpretation of curation isn't in line with our guidelines. The actions I see taken on this regex tag feel like a separate camp, and I do think the camps very much exist, even if I've (necessarily) simplified a bit. It's not the only three philosophies on curation, just one way of looking at it that I think is pertinent to the thread at hand. I did remove Dharman's link from #1 because he said he wasn't in this camp.

I don't know, exactly, that's the problem. Theres clearly 3 entirely different opinions just within this comment thread that all lump into group 1. does that mean you need camps 1 through 5? 8? 10? just present your opinion instead.

@KevinB I adjusted the question a bit and tried to tone it down emotionally, but I think the camps are useful to show the broad philosophical approaches to curation that are at battle here. I've also tried to clarify that it's a thought model for the purposes of discussion, not a perfect snapshot of reality. Maybe it's no better than before, but I'm still open to ideas.

To be clear: I don't think every question needs to be at the level of a FAQ. But they do need to be at a level where they could a) be relevant to someone else besides the OP and b) presented in a way that such a "someone else" could plausibly find it or at least be easily directed to it by a regular. But more importantly, they need to be properly focused, to a very high standard - because even relatively uninteresting questions are read far more often than they are written or edited.

Even the most unremarkable dupes get tens of views. (I don't think my filter for "self-dupes" - where OP re-asks the same question - worked properly.)

In short: if your question is too specific to your needs because you don't actually need a question answered, it will be closed and deleted. If it's too specific because you have more than one need, or because you focus attention on irrelevant things, or fail to include relevant things, it will be closed and you have 9 days to fix it.

" changing the input CLog_DMT_HPCC2_IWHT91731695_242_AFT1_2019-05-02T07.51.43 to I123_456_ABC_01_test. How is that allowed?" because the exact content of the input does not change what the question is. Questions seeking debugging advice are required to have a proper MRE, and the detailed contents of the string just make the underlying question harder to understand. (Similarly, when describing the behaviour of the code, it's important to use the actual names of the capturing groups.) It doesn't change the author's intent at all, and I frankly can't understand why you'd think it does.

In my edit, I was careful to ensure that the description of the code behaviour - both in terms of the names of the capturing groups, and the text they capture - correspond to the changed input. That is how a MRE works. It is not required to be an accurate reflection of the actual code that originally motivated OP to ask. It is required to reliably and accurately demonstrate the problem, as simply and directly as possible.

"The edit basically removed the failing input entirely CLOB_ABCD_6KW_SYSTEM_609-784_IWHT91831863_197_ACB_01_2019-05-02T07.03.27" - Yes; and I replaced it with a simpler input that fails in the same way, for the same reason when tested with a corresponding simpler regex  (also provided) that has the same problem.

@KarlKnechtel Thanks for clarifying. A few points: (1) I understand you think you were preserving the author's intent, but we don't know which parts of that pattern were important, really. The answer used that exact input and was accepted, so "generifying" the input pattern invalidates that accepted answer, and it doesn't make the question more useful to future visitors, either. Input is super important in regex--let the author minimize it themselves. If they can't, then we can close it rather than make a guess that may well be wrong.

We do know what parts of the pattern were important to characterizing the problem, because OP described the parts I removed as working correctly.

@KarlKnechtel (2) I shouldn't have tried to defend this question, it's fine to close because it's unclear. Regex is just an impossible tag to discuss or defend. I mostly saw it as an opportunity to fight against the patterns I'm seeing camp #1 style curation, and was upset by what I feel were recent DV/closures on questions I'd answered for the same reasons--sure, not 100% the most canonical question, but perfectly answerable and no clear dupe. But unfortunately I lumped Dharmin's curation which is probably OK with the "close everything against a wiki" curation which I still think is harmful.

@KarlKnechtel (3) I don't think views or "only matters to OP" are always the best metrics for deletion. How do you know it's only helped OP? Like I said, as an avid searcher on the site, I've had my butt saved many times by questions that are 6 years old and have on the order of 40 views. Although this question is probably not going to be that useful to FVs, many others certainly are. It's hard to know what'll be useful to someone. As long as the question is otherwise on topic, I think it should be left up, and comments seem like the best way to clarify questions that have an attempt.

@KarlKnechtel (4) Finally, I'm asking for someone to show me the help center guide that says "if a question is only useful to you, don't bother posting it". Or any similar language/sentiment to even a small extent, and I'll stand corrected. (Yes, the MRE is important for genericizing it, but subtle nuances can make that a bit tricky in cases like the regex case here--oversimplification is a risk, so I don't think that applies here). Thanks for the conversation, I appreciate it, and I apologize for calling you out in this thread. I think post-edit a couple days ago, my answer is less targeted.

@KarlKnechtel Also (last comment), when I first responded here, I didn't realize the question at hand here was as old as it was. I wrote the answer initially thinking it was freshly posted and freshly deleted. So the deletion is probably OK given the time it's been up. I still find the trend I'm discussing concerning, and stretching site guidelines. For the record, I close and DV a huge number of posts, but only ones that are unanswerable, not ones that just happen to be fairly specific and likely unpopular in sideline tags I frequent. As I wrote in my answer, this is unclear enough to close.
